# regex pattern for name is not working in adobe cq5

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, aem, forms

i need a regex pattern for name field in which i want to allow character a-z, A-Z and ' - and white space. i am currently using this code but it is giving an error.

```
final String regexpattern = "/[a-zA-Z\s-']*/";
```

Comment: It's a valid regex.  what error are you getting?

Answer (score 1):

You have to add another `\` before `\s`, and add `^` and `$` for match begin and end.

```
final String regexpattern = "/^[a-zA-Z\\s'-]*$/";
```

Comment: Hi xdazz, thanks it is working fine can u help me for some regex patteren also as i have no idea of these like if i have to allow the all characters excluding ^<>%*()#!?

Answer (score 0):

Your regex (when it is no longer malformed - see below how to fix that) **will always match** because you do not use anchors (`^` - start of string, and `$` - end of string) and use a `*` quantifier (*match 1 or more symbols matching the preceding subpattern, as many as possible*).

However, just adding `^` and `$` will not fix the pattern, because you are using 1 backslash with `\s` inside a C string (i.e. inside a string literal "..."). The backslash is treated as an escape symbol and is not taken into account as `"\s"` is an invalid escape sequence. Inside a character class in regex (i.e. in `[...]`), a hyphen creates a *range*. Your `s-'` creates a range from `s` (dec. code 115) to `'` (dec. code 39). Since **in a range inside a character class the codes must go from the lowest to the highest**, an error is thrown.

You may just use

```
final String regexpattern = "/^[a-zA-Z\\s-']*$/";
```

It is possible because the hyphen after a shorthand class `\s` does not create a range and is considered a literal. As best practice, you can move it to the end of the character class as xdazz did.

As for your additional question in comment:

> i have to allow the all characters excluding `^<>%*()#!?`

Just use a negated character class: a pair of square brackets with a starting `^` inside it:

```
final String regexpattern = "/^[^<>%*()#!^?]*$/";
                              1 2        3
```

Here, the first `^` is the start-of-string anchor, and the second caret is the negation of the characters inside the character class. The third caret is a literal symbol `^`.